# Prints a minimal set of packages required to install the package

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dependencies, package

I have to create a data structure that represents the dependencies between packages.

I thought I could simply use a graph, but the problem is that some packages can depend on one of the "optional" packages, and we have to choose which one of these optimal package is more convenient to install (basically, from these optional choices, we need to install the best).

For example, suppose I have the following situtation:

> 1. package1:
> 2. package2: package1
> 3. package3: package1, package2
> 4. package4: package1 | package3
> 5. package5: package1, package2 | package3

This situation means that:

> 1. package 1 has no dependencies.
> 2. package 2 depends on package 1 (we need to install package 1).
> 3. package 3 depends on package 1 and 2 (we need to install both)
> 4. package 4 depends package 1 or 3 (we can install either 1 or 3, but we need to choose the best choice, which means the choice that make
>      package 4 depend on less packages)
> 5. package 5 depends on package 1, and it depends also either on package 2 or 3 (again, we need to chose the best choice)

Now, the problem is clearly when we can choose between different packages.

How do we choose them?

Why, for example, package 4 should depend on package 1 instead of 3?

We could try checking which packages package 1 and package 3 depends on, but what about if we have 10000 choices, but we need just 1 best choice? It would need thousands of loops and stuff too much complicated. There might be something simple, but I don't know what.

This kind of trying to choose which one is better to install seems to lead to a recursive algorithm somhow, and this already blows my mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a directed graph with two types of nodes:

- `package` nodes, whose children are combined using an AND logic
- `OR` nodes, whose children are combined using an OR logic

All the arcs starting from a node represent its dependencies.

For your example this would create the following graph:
[image: dependency graph]

If you have to evaluate the minimum set of dependencies for a package, you can visit the graph using a depth-first-search algorithm:

- when you visit a `package` node you sum the number of dependencies of its children
- when you visit an `OR` node you consider the minimum number of dependencies of its children

**Example code**

Here is an example of how to implement this in python (I've used python as its syntax is almost like pseudo-code; you should be able to get the gist of it):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Package:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, name, dependencies):
        self.name = name
        self.dependencies = set(dependencies)
    # Needed to print the package
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    # This method returns the optimal set of dependencies for this package
    def getOptimalDependencies(self):
        optimalDependencies = set()
        for dependency in self.dependencies:
            optimalDependencies = optimalDependencies.union(dependency.getOptimalDependencies())
        optimalDependencies.add(self)
        return optimalDependencies

class Or:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, dependencies):
        self.dependencies = set(dependencies)
    # This method returns the optimal set of dependencies
    # of the packages combined with this 'OR'
    def getOptimalDependencies(self):
        optimalDependencies = set()
        for dependency in self.dependencies:
            alternativeDependencies = dependency.getOptimalDependencies()
            if len(optimalDependencies) == 0 or len(alternativeDependencies) < len(optimalDependencies):
                optimalDependencies = alternativeDependencies
        return optimalDependencies
```

You can then create the packages of your example as:

```
package1 = Package("package1", [])
package2 = Package("package2", [package1])
package3 = Package("package3", [package1, package2])
package4 = Package("package4", [Or([package1, package3])])
package5 = Package("package5", [package1, Or([package2, package3])])
```

To get the list of optimal dependecies for a `package5` you can then call `package5.getOptimalDependencies()`.

If we print it with:

```
print(','.join(map(str, package5.getOptimalDependencies())))
```

we get:

```
package2,package1,package5
```

If you have dependencies cycles you have to insert some control for that.

Comment: I've added some code in python to illustrate the idea. You can then reimplemented in your language of choice. The algorithm can be improved by avoiding to recompute the dependecies of a package each time its node is visited, but I chose to keep the code simple so that it was more readable

Comment: Why should `getOptimalDependencies` method find the shortest path? Why I am not seeing why...

Comment: You can proved it by induction. You know the set of optimal dependencies for each leaf node (those that have no outgoing arcs and therefore no dependencies). If you know the optimal dependencies for each child of a given node, then you know the optimal dependencies of that node: for a `package` node it will be the union of the dependecies of its children, for an `OR` node it will be the smallest set of dependencies among those of its children. We are basically visiting the graph starting from its leafs and making our way up to the node whose dependencies we want to find.

Comment: There's a problem with your function (solution in general). Suppose we have the following situation: 
    `A: B | C, D | E`.
    `B: G, H, M`.
    `C: K, N`.
    `D: G, H, M`.
    `E: L, J`.
    
If if we run your algorithm it is going to return the wrong answer for the package `A`, because your algorithm actually returns the best choice locally (when visiting single nodes and OrNodes) and does not take into account the overall state of `A`. Maybe we need some checks...

Answer (score 0):

We can model it as a pseudo-boolean optimization problem.

Assume there are `k` packages. Define k Boolean variables `x_i`, where `x_i` is true if and only if the final choice is to install the package_i. Thus, the objective is to minimize the summation of `x_i` where 1 <= i <= k. If each package requires different "cost" to install (for example, package size), you could minimize weighted sum of `x_i` instead.

To model the constraint "package5: package1, package2 | package3", we could find that "package5 is installed" *implies* "package1 is installed". If the pseudo-boolean optimizer supports constraints represented in [Conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), then it could be written as

```
(!x_5 + x_1)
```

if only linear inequalities are allowed, then it is

```
(1 - x_5) + x_1 >= 1
```

The other half, "package5 is installed" *implies* "package2 and/or package3 is installed", can be written as

```
(!x_5 + x_2 + x_3)
```

or

```
(1 - x_5) + x_2 + x_3 >= 1
```

Finally, you must assert the package you required.

```
x_k
```

or

```
x_k = 1
```

Now that we've modeled the problem as pseudo-boolean optimization problem, you could call any solver available and solve it. You could refer to [Pseudo Boolean Competition](http://www.cril.univ-artois.fr/PB12/) for state-of-the-art solvers.